# C#  property of type  List<T> that can receive many List<Types>

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I see many online samples talking about Generics `List<T>`.

I'm just not sure if `T` is just a way for the narrator to define "any type" or if I can actually use the syntax `List<T>` to define a property that can receive any type of LIST.

If not, then what is the right way to define a property that can be populated with either `List<MyType>`, or `List<YourType>` or `List<AnyType>` ??

The reason I'm asking is also because on my WebService that property is giving me the following error:
`The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

and off course I already have the `using System.Collections.Generic;` on top.

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDbSync
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int UploadTable(SecurityToken token, TableData table);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SecurityToken
    {
        string id = "";
        string token = "";

        [DataMember]
        public string ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Token
        {
            get { return token; }
            set { token = value; }
        }
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class TableData
    {
        List<T> data;
        string tableName = "";

        [DataMember]
        public string TableName
        {
            get { return tableName; }
            set { tableName = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public List<T> Data
        {
            get { return data; }
            set { data = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about how [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) work.

Comment: Please read my amended last part of the question. thanks

Comment: @BoltClock: Didn't know you became a mod, congrats!! :)

Comment: I hope you got my answer and  check the code for you ....you just need to add <T>  with the class name will resolve you error and plez do read about the generatics at link given by me

Comment: @Developer - you should read basic of Generic of c# will help you.....................

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it easily

ready about c# generics ..............

[An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

Do define property as

```
class myclass<TValue> 
{     
     public TValue myproperty
     {         
         get {             
               return (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(Value, tyepof(TValue));         
            }     
        }
}
```

Code for you

```
[DataContract]     
public class TableData <T>
    {         List<T> data;         string tableName = "";          [DataMember]         public string TableName         {             get { return tableName; }             set { tableName = value; }         }          [DataMember]         public List<T> Data         {             get { return data; }             set { data = value; }         }     }
```

Comment: and "TValue" is the same as putting "T" ?

Comment: @Developer - yes................T is jut stand for type than you can replace with any valid string....

Comment: Can u please check my code (I updated my original question) and help me finding why is giving me that error? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Now the "[ServiceContract]" is giving the following error: Error Using the generic type 'StackOverflow.TableData<T>' requires 1 type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`T` stands for the type you apply during declaration of that type. Let me give a an example. Here is a custom class defined with a generic type:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

This class has one property `MyProperty` of type `T`. But that isn't the real type, it stands for the type you write when you create an instance of your class.

```
var myClassObject1 = new MyClass<int>();
var myClassObject2 = new MyClass<string>();
```

From this moment on your variable `myClassObject1` is of type `MyClass<int>` and `myClassObject2` is of type `MyClass<string>`. You get the properties of the classes like this:

```
int intValue = myClassObject1.MyProperty;
string stringValue = myClassObject2.MyProperty;
```

That's in short the basics how gererics work. For deeper informations I highly advice you to read the "Introduction to C# Generics" Pranay Rana mentioned in his answer.

**Edit**

You haven't specified the type in your class, do it like that:

```
[DataContract]      
public class TableData<T>      
{          
    List<T> data;          
    string tableName = "";            

    [DataMember]          
    public string TableName          
    {
        get { return tableName; }              
        set { tableName = value; }          
    }            

    [DataMember]          
    public List<T> Data          
    {              
        get { return data; }              
        set { data = value; }          
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Developer: See my Edit section.

Comment: That works but how can I ensure that the ServiceContract remains the same for any client that passes me different TableData.DATA lists? Or shall I have to create different ServiceContract calls (one x type expected)? I was hoping generics would handle that...

Comment: @Developer: unfortunately I'm not an expert in WCF. I've added the tags to your question, maybe some other can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You declared no `T` type substitute in `TableData`, thus `T` is not known. Try declaring your class like this:

```
public class TableData<T>
```

This gives you `T`, and forces consumer to create `TableData` instances along with a type:

```
var myData = new TableData<string>();
```

Above, every `T` type would become a `string` type.

Comment: So that way, I would have to give a type to the "ServiceContract" call LoadTable(SecurityToken token, TableData<TypeX> table). Is that right?

Cause ideally i would want that "ServiceContract" call to be reused by as many clients as possible each passing me a different "DATA" value containing different List types inside that DATA property. Is that possible ?

Comment: I guess this could work. So, for instance, you might have a `TableData<string>` which would expose a `Name` and a `List<string>` as the (tabular) data. At least it would in plain .NET code, I'm not sure how WCF supports generics.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that WCF doesn't support generics so if it forces me to write 10 different calls (one per type), then why use generics at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Surely, it will error because you haven't defined the type T in your code. T stands for template of any type ... so you have to define a type such as string, int, object or your custom type that can be a class that you have created.
See comments in your code.

```
[DataContract]
public class TableData
{
    List<T> data;                    //Here what do you want in the data object? a List of strings or a List of your custom defined class types? so you declare List<string> data; or List<MyClass> data; Although I prefer you use IList instead of List.
    string tableName = "";

    [DataMember]
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return tableName; }
        set { tableName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Data          //Then here as well you use public IList<string> Data or public IList<Myclass> data and it should be fine.
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}
```